# Prove $u$ is a unit if and only if $N(u) = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

The norm $N:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined by $N(a+b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}) = |a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 - 6abc|$ is multiplicative. (Already proven). Show that $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a unit if and only if $N(\alpha) = 1$.

So far proved it one direction, but am struggling with the other.

Proof $\rightarrow$
Let $\alpha$ be a unit, so by defintion $\exists \beta$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1$. We can then use the norm, knowing that $N(\alpha\beta) = |(1)^3 + 2(0)^3 + 4(0)^3 - 6(1)(0)(0)| = 1$. Since the norm is multiplicative, $N(\alpha\beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta) = 1$, and since the results of the norms have to be positive integers, we know $N(\alpha)=1$.

Proof $\leftarrow$ Let $N(\alpha)$ = 1. Then for $\alpha = a+b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}$, $|a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 - 6abc|=1$

Any help on where to go?

Answer (score 4):

$R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt[3]2]$ is a free Abelian group of rank $3$, that is isomorphic
as an Abelian group to $\Bbb Z^3$. A convenient basis for this is
$1$, $\sqrt[3]2$ and $\sqrt[3]4$.

If $\alpha\in R$, multiplication by $\alpha$ determines an endomorphism
of $R$; a group homomorphism from $R$ to $R$. We can represent this
by a matrix by considering its action on one's favourite basis
(say, $1$, $\sqrt[3]2$, $\sqrt[3]4$). Then $N(\alpha)=|\det A|$.
(You can prove this by the explicit formula you already have).

If $N(\alpha)=1$, then $\det A=\pm1$. An endomorphism of $\Bbb Z^3$
with determinant $1$ is an automorphism, so a bijection. In terms of
$A$ then multiplication by $\alpha$ is a bijection. Therefore, there is
$\beta\in R$ with $\alpha\beta=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if you embed $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ into $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega]$ where $\omega := e^{2 \pi i / 3}$, then
$$N(a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4}) = \left| (a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4}) (a + b \omega \sqrt[3]{2} + c \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{4}) (a + b \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2} + c \omega \sqrt[3]{4}) \right|.$$
(This expression is heavily inspired by the definition of norm in Galois theory, of which your definition is close to being a special case.)

Now, multiply the last two factors on the right hand side, and you should get an expression for $\pm$ of the inverse of $a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4}$ which lies in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.  (With the sign being determined by the sign of $a^3 + 2 b^3 + 4 c^3 - 6abc$.)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\;N(\alpha)=\pm1\;$ means that the minimal polynomial of $\;\alpha\;$ over the rationals is of the form

$$p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x\pm1\;,\;\;a_k\in\Bbb Z$$

Taking the reciprocal of the above polynomial we get a polynomial that vanishes at $\;\frac1\alpha\;$ (this much is always true whenever $\;\alpha\neq0\;$ and we're working over a field), thus $\;\frac1\alpha\;$ is a root of

$$f(x)=\pm x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+1$$

and thus $\;\frac1\alpha\;$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: True, but being an algebraic integer does not necessarily tell you that it lies in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$; also, the fact that the norm is connected with the minimal polynomial is non-obvious.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Indeed so. The element $\;\frac1\alpha\;$ is for sure in the field extension of the rationals where $\;\alpha\;$ is, and its min. polynomial dividing the given reciprocal means it is an alg. integer. About the minimal polynomial I'd say that for such a question one could usually assume the OP already knows the role the norm and the trace of an algebraic element play within the minimal polynomial...Anyway, if the OP has some doubt he could ask. Y por cierto: bienvenido de regreso, aunque fuera por poco tiempo.

Comment: "Anyway, if the OP has some doubt he could ask."  The OP may not be a "he".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by DonAntonio, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is of the form
$$p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x\pm1,\quad a_k\in\Bbb Z$$
Then $p(\alpha)=0$ implies
$$
 \alpha (\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2\alpha+a_1) = \pm 1
$$
and so the inverse of $\alpha$ is $\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2\alpha+a_1 \in \mathbb Z[\alpha] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

For $K$ a number field the norm $N(\alpha)$ of an element $\alpha$ of $K$ is the determinant of the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $m_{\alpha} :x \mapsto \alpha x$. Assume that $\alpha$ is inside the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ of $K$. In a $\mathbb{Z}$ basis of $\mathcal{O}$ the map $m_{\alpha}$ has a matrix with integral coefficients. Therefore $\alpha$ satisfies an equation of the form
$$\alpha^n - a_1 \alpha^{n-1} + \cdots + (-1)^n a_n= 0$$ with $a_i \in\mathbb{Z}$. Note that $a_n= N(\alpha)$. Assume now that $N(\alpha)=\pm 1$. Then we can write 
$$\alpha( \alpha^{n-1} - a_1 \alpha^{n-2} + \cdots) = \pm 1$$ Therefore the inverse $\alpha^{-1}$  is in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and so an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The part I like is this: the polynomial $ \; x^3 + 2 y^3 + 4 z^3 - 6xyz \; \;$ integrally represents every prime $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ as well as every prime $q \equiv 1$ whenever we can write $q = u^2 + 27 v^2$ with integers.

On the other hand, if we have a prime $r = 4 u^2 + 2uv + 7 v^2,$ not only is $r$ not integrally represented, but $x^3 + 2 y^3 + 4 z^3 - 6xyz$ is not divisible by $r$ unless $x,y,z$ are all divisible by $r.$ One aspect of this is that the exponent of such a prime, in a represented number,  is divisible by 3. I deliberately stopped the list at $343 = 7^3.$

Maybe I should add that it was an educated guess that we could take $x,y,z \geq 0.$ i am not entirely sure, but that is what I did for this output.

---

```
     1      x: 1   y: 0   z: 0 n : 1 =   1 
     2      x: 0   y: 1   z: 0 n : 2 =  2
     3      x: 1   y: 1   z: 0 n : 3 =  3
     4      x: 0   y: 0   z: 1 n : 4 =  2^2
     5      x: 1   y: 0   z: 1 n : 5 =  5
     6      x: 0   y: 1   z: 1 n : 6 =  2 3
     8      x: 2   y: 0   z: 0 n : 8 =  2^3
     9      x: 1   y: 2   z: 1 n : 9 =  3^2
    10      x: 2   y: 1   z: 0 n : 10 =  2 5
    11      x: 3   y: 2   z: 1 n : 11 =  11
    12      x: 2   y: 0   z: 1 n : 12 =  2^2 3
    15      x: 3   y: 1   z: 1 n : 15 =  3 5
    16      x: 0   y: 2   z: 0 n : 16 =  2^4
    17      x: 1   y: 2   z: 0 n : 17 =  17
    18      x: 2   y: 1   z: 2 n : 18 =  2 3^2
    20      x: 0   y: 2   z: 1 n : 20 =  2^2 5
    22      x: 2   y: 3   z: 2 n : 22 =  2 11
    23      x: 1   y: 1   z: 2 n : 23 =  23
    24      x: 2   y: 2   z: 0 n : 24 =  2^3 3
    25      x: 1   y: 2   z: 2 n : 25 =  5^2
    27      x: 3   y: 0   z: 0 n : 27 =  3^3
    29      x: 3   y: 1   z: 0 n : 29 =  29
    30      x: 2   y: 3   z: 1 n : 30 =  2 3 5
    31      x: 3   y: 0   z: 1 n : 31 =  31
    32      x: 0   y: 0   z: 2 n : 32 =  2^5
    33      x: 1   y: 0   z: 2 n : 33 =  3 11
    34      x: 0   y: 1   z: 2 n : 34 =  2 17
    36      x: 4   y: 2   z: 1 n : 36 =  2^2 3^2
    40      x: 2   y: 0   z: 2 n : 40 =  2^3 5
    41      x: 1   y: 3   z: 1 n : 41 =  41
    43      x: 3   y: 2   z: 0 n : 43 =  43
    44      x: 4   y: 2   z: 3 n : 44 =  2^2 11
    45      x: 5   y: 4   z: 2 n : 45 =  3^2 5
    46      x: 4   y: 1   z: 1 n : 46 =  2 23
    47      x: 3   y: 4   z: 3 n : 47 =  47
    48      x: 0   y: 2   z: 2 n : 48 =  2^4 3
    50      x: 4   y: 1   z: 2 n : 50 =  2 5^2
    51      x: 1   y: 3   z: 2 n : 51 =  3 17
    53      x: 5   y: 2   z: 2 n : 53 =  53
    54      x: 0   y: 3   z: 0 n : 54 =  2 3^3
    55      x: 1   y: 3   z: 0 n : 55 =  5 11
    58      x: 0   y: 3   z: 1 n : 58 =  2 29
    59      x: 3   y: 0   z: 2 n : 59 =  59
    60      x: 2   y: 2   z: 3 n : 60 =  2^2 3 5
    62      x: 2   y: 3   z: 0 n : 62 =  2 31
    64      x: 4   y: 0   z: 0 n : 64 =  2^6
    66      x: 4   y: 1   z: 0 n : 66 =  2 3 11
    68      x: 4   y: 0   z: 1 n : 68 =  2^2 17
    69      x: 5   y: 2   z: 3 n : 69 =  3 23
    71      x: 7   y: 5   z: 3 n : 71 =  71
    72      x: 2   y: 4   z: 2 n : 72 =  2^3 3^2
    75      x: 5   y: 3   z: 4 n : 75 =  3 5^2
    80      x: 4   y: 2   z: 0 n : 80 =  2^4 5
    81      x: 3   y: 3   z: 0 n : 81 =  3^4
    82      x: 2   y: 1   z: 3 n : 82 =  2 41
    83      x: 3   y: 1   z: 3 n : 83 =  83
    85      x: 5   y: 2   z: 1 n : 85 =  5 17
    86      x: 0   y: 3   z: 2 n : 86 =  2 43
    87      x: 3   y: 4   z: 1 n : 87 =  3 29
    88      x: 6   y: 4   z: 2 n : 88 =  2^3 11
    89      x: 1   y: 2   z: 3 n : 89 =  89
    90      x: 4   y: 5   z: 4 n : 90 =  2 3^2 5
    92      x: 2   y: 4   z: 1 n : 92 =  2^2 23
    93      x: 1   y: 1   z: 3 n : 93 =  3 31
    94      x: 6   y: 3   z: 4 n : 94 =  2 47
    96      x: 4   y: 0   z: 2 n : 96 =  2^5 3
    99      x: 5   y: 1   z: 2 n : 99 =  3^2 11
   100      x: 2   y: 4   z: 3 n : 100 =  2^2 5^2
   101      x: 5   y: 1   z: 1 n : 101 =  101
   102      x: 4   y: 1   z: 3 n : 102 =  2 3 17
   106      x: 4   y: 5   z: 2 n : 106 =  2 53
   107      x: 5   y: 5   z: 2 n : 107 =  107
   108      x: 0   y: 0   z: 3 n : 108 =  2^2 3^3
   109      x: 1   y: 0   z: 3 n : 109 =  109
   110      x: 0   y: 1   z: 3 n : 110 =  2 5 11
   113      x: 1   y: 4   z: 2 n : 113 =  113
   115      x: 3   y: 5   z: 3 n : 115 =  5 23
   116      x: 2   y: 0   z: 3 n : 116 =  2^2 29
   118      x: 4   y: 3   z: 0 n : 118 =  2 59
   120      x: 6   y: 2   z: 2 n : 120 =  2^3 3 5
   121      x: 3   y: 3   z: 4 n : 121 =  11^2
   123      x: 3   y: 4   z: 4 n : 123 =  3 41
   124      x: 0   y: 2   z: 3 n : 124 =  2^2 31
   125      x: 5   y: 0   z: 0 n : 125 =  5^3
   127      x: 5   y: 1   z: 0 n : 127 =  127
   128      x: 0   y: 4   z: 0 n : 128 =  2^7
   129      x: 1   y: 4   z: 0 n : 129 =  3 43
   131      x: 7   y: 4   z: 5 n : 131 =  131
   132      x: 0   y: 4   z: 1 n : 132 =  2^2 3 11
   135      x: 3   y: 0   z: 3 n : 135 =  3^3 5
   136      x: 2   y: 4   z: 0 n : 136 =  2^3 17
   137      x: 5   y: 4   z: 1 n : 137 =  137
   138      x: 6   y: 5   z: 2 n : 138 =  2 3 23
   141      x: 5   y: 2   z: 0 n : 141 =  3 47
   142      x: 6   y: 7   z: 5 n : 142 =  2 71
   144      x: 4   y: 2   z: 4 n : 144 =  2^4 3^2
   145      x: 5   y: 1   z: 3 n : 145 =  5 29
   149      x: 7   y: 3   z: 4 n : 149 =  149
   150      x: 8   y: 5   z: 3 n : 150 =  2 3 5^2
   153      x: 5   y: 4   z: 5 n : 153 =  3^2 17
   155      x: 3   y: 4   z: 0 n : 155 =  5 31
   157      x: 5   y: 0   z: 2 n : 157 =  157
   159      x: 9   y: 7   z: 4 n : 159 =  3 53
   160      x: 0   y: 4   z: 2 n : 160 =  2^5 5
   162      x: 0   y: 3   z: 3 n : 162 =  2 3^4
   164      x: 6   y: 2   z: 1 n : 164 =  2^2 41
   165      x: 1   y: 4   z: 3 n : 165 =  3 5 11
   166      x: 6   y: 3   z: 1 n : 166 =  2 83
   167      x: 7   y: 4   z: 2 n : 167 =  167
   170      x: 2   y: 5   z: 2 n : 170 =  2 5 17
   172      x: 4   y: 0   z: 3 n : 172 =  2^2 43
   173      x: 3   y: 5   z: 4 n : 173 =  173
   174      x: 2   y: 3   z: 4 n : 174 =  2 3 29
   176      x: 4   y: 6   z: 4 n : 176 =  2^4 11
   177      x: 7   y: 3   z: 2 n : 177 =  3 59
   178      x: 6   y: 1   z: 2 n : 178 =  2 89
   179      x: 5   y: 3   z: 0 n : 179 =  179
   180      x: 8   y: 4   z: 5 n : 180 =  2^2 3^2 5
   184      x: 2   y: 2   z: 4 n : 184 =  2^3 23
   186      x: 6   y: 1   z: 1 n : 186 =  2 3 31
   187      x: 7   y: 8   z: 5 n : 187 =  11 17
   188      x: 8   y: 6   z: 3 n : 188 =  2^2 47
   191      x: 3   y: 5   z: 1 n : 191 =  191
   192      x: 4   y: 4   z: 0 n : 192 =  2^6 3
   197      x: 7   y: 5   z: 6 n : 197 =  197
   198      x: 4   y: 5   z: 1 n : 198 =  2 3^2 11
   200      x: 2   y: 4   z: 4 n : 200 =  2^3 5^2
   202      x: 2   y: 5   z: 1 n : 202 =  2 101
   204      x: 6   y: 4   z: 1 n : 204 =  2^2 3 17
   205      x: 7   y: 5   z: 2 n : 205 =  5 41
   207      x: 11   y: 7   z: 5 n : 207 =  3^2 23
   212      x: 4   y: 4   z: 5 n : 212 =  2^2 53
   213      x: 3   y: 1   z: 4 n : 213 =  3 71
   214      x: 4   y: 5   z: 5 n : 214 =  2 107
   215      x: 7   y: 2   z: 3 n : 215 =  5 43
   216      x: 6   y: 0   z: 0 n : 216 =  2^3 3^3
   218      x: 2   y: 1   z: 4 n : 218 =  2 109
   220      x: 6   y: 0   z: 1 n : 220 =  2^2 5 11
   223      x: 1   y: 5   z: 2 n : 223 =  223
   225      x: 1   y: 2   z: 4 n : 225 =  3^2 5^2
   226      x: 4   y: 1   z: 4 n : 226 =  2 113
   227      x: 5   y: 7   z: 4 n : 227 =  227
   229      x: 5   y: 5   z: 1 n : 229 =  229
   230      x: 6   y: 3   z: 5 n : 230 =  2 5 23
   232      x: 6   y: 2   z: 0 n : 232 =  2^3 29
   233      x: 5   y: 0   z: 3 n : 233 =  233
   235      x: 1   y: 1   z: 4 n : 235 =  5 47
   236      x: 0   y: 4   z: 3 n : 236 =  2^2 59
   239      x: 1   y: 3   z: 4 n : 239 =  239
   240      x: 4   y: 6   z: 2 n : 240 =  2^4 3 5
   242      x: 8   y: 3   z: 3 n : 242 =  2 11^2
   243      x: 3   y: 6   z: 3 n : 243 =  3^5
   246      x: 8   y: 3   z: 4 n : 246 =  2 3 41
   248      x: 6   y: 0   z: 2 n : 248 =  2^3 31
   249      x: 9   y: 4   z: 4 n : 249 =  3 83
   250      x: 0   y: 5   z: 0 n : 250 =  2 5^3
   251      x: 1   y: 5   z: 0 n : 251 =  251
   253      x: 5   y: 4   z: 0 n : 253 =  11 23
   254      x: 0   y: 5   z: 1 n : 254 =  2 127
   255      x: 7   y: 7   z: 3 n : 255 =  3 5 17
   256      x: 0   y: 0   z: 4 n : 256 =  2^8
   257      x: 1   y: 0   z: 4 n : 257 =  257
   258      x: 0   y: 1   z: 4 n : 258 =  2 3 43
   261      x: 5   y: 7   z: 5 n : 261 =  3^2 29
   262      x: 10   y: 7   z: 4 n : 262 =  2 131
   263      x: 5   y: 1   z: 4 n : 263 =  263
   264      x: 2   y: 0   z: 4 n : 264 =  2^3 3 11
   265      x: 9   y: 6   z: 7 n : 265 =  5 53
   267      x: 7   y: 3   z: 5 n : 267 =  3 89
   269      x: 1   y: 5   z: 3 n : 269 =  269
   270      x: 6   y: 3   z: 0 n : 270 =  2 3^3 5
   272      x: 0   y: 2   z: 4 n : 272 =  2^4 17
   274      x: 2   y: 5   z: 4 n : 274 =  2 137
   275      x: 3   y: 6   z: 2 n : 275 =  5^2 11
   276      x: 4   y: 6   z: 5 n : 276 =  2^2 3 23
   277      x: 3   y: 5   z: 0 n : 277 =  277
   279      x: 7   y: 2   z: 1 n : 279 =  3^2 31
   281      x: 9   y: 8   z: 4 n : 281 =  281
   282      x: 0   y: 5   z: 2 n : 282 =  2 3 47
   283      x: 3   y: 0   z: 4 n : 283 =  283
   284      x: 10   y: 6   z: 7 n : 284 =  2^2 71
   288      x: 8   y: 4   z: 2 n : 288 =  2^5 3^2
   289      x: 1   y: 4   z: 4 n : 289 =  17^2
   290      x: 6   y: 5   z: 1 n : 290 =  2 5 29
   293      x: 7   y: 1   z: 2 n : 293 =  293
   295      x: 3   y: 4   z: 5 n : 295 =  5 59
   297      x: 9   y: 6   z: 3 n : 297 =  3^3 11
   298      x: 8   y: 7   z: 3 n : 298 =  2 149
   300      x: 6   y: 8   z: 5 n : 300 =  2^2 3 5^2
   303      x: 7   y: 6   z: 2 n : 303 =  3 101
   306      x: 10   y: 5   z: 4 n : 306 =  2 3^2 17
   307      x: 7   y: 1   z: 1 n : 307 =  307
   310      x: 0   y: 3   z: 4 n : 310 =  2 5 31
   311      x: 3   y: 3   z: 5 n : 311 =  311
   314      x: 4   y: 5   z: 0 n : 314 =  2 157
   317      x: 9   y: 4   z: 3 n : 317 =  317
   318      x: 8   y: 9   z: 7 n : 318 =  2 3 53
   319      x: 11   y: 9   z: 5 n : 319 =  11 29
   320      x: 4   y: 0   z: 4 n : 320 =  2^6 5
   321      x: 9   y: 10   z: 7 n : 321 =  3 107
   324      x: 6   y: 0   z: 3 n : 324 =  2^2 3^4
   327      x: 7   y: 1   z: 3 n : 327 =  3 109
   328      x: 2   y: 6   z: 2 n : 328 =  2^3 41
   330      x: 6   y: 1   z: 4 n : 330 =  2 3 5 11
   332      x: 2   y: 6   z: 3 n : 332 =  2^2 83
   334      x: 4   y: 7   z: 4 n : 334 =  2 167
   339      x: 5   y: 5   z: 6 n : 339 =  3 113
   340      x: 4   y: 2   z: 5 n : 340 =  2^2 5 17
   341      x: 5   y: 2   z: 5 n : 341 =  11 31
   343      x: 7   y: 0   z: 0 n : 343 =  7^3
```

---

Comment: Wow, amazing facts!